# Conditional hiding worksheet from multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

I need a sheet in Excel to activate if any cells in a column are selected as "Yes", but my VBA code won't stick - simple enough to do for one cell, but the whole column is throwing me. The cells are a drop down list with solely the options "Yes" or "No"

Currently trying:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$H$11:$H$23" Then
            If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H11:H23").Value = "Yes" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: You are checking the entire range where the `Target` may refer to a single cell also. Your `Range("H11:H23").Value = 'Yes'` seems a syntax error.

Comment: Note that `ActiveWorkbook` is not the workbook the code is in (it is the workbook that is on top while the code is executed). The workbook the code is in would be `ThisWorkbook`. In any doubts use `ThisWorkbook` and avoid anything that has an `Active` in its name. They are only needed in rare cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier solution without looping would be to count the `Yes` using [WorksheetFunction.CountIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif).

Use the following to show `Sheet2` if **at least one cell** has the `Yes`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TestRange As Range
    Set TestRange = Me.Range("H11:H23")

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, TestRange) Is Nothing Then  'if target is in test range

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(TestRange, "Yes") > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If **all cells** in the test range need to be `Yes` then change it to

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(TestRange, "Yes") = TestRange.Cells.Count Then
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim Inrng As Boolean

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H11:H23")) Is Nothing Then
        'Set a boolean variable to false
        Inrng = False
        'Set a range to loop
        Set rng = Me.Range("H11:H23")
        'Start looping the range
        For Each cell In rng
            'Convert the value of a cell to Upper case to avoid case sensitive issues
            If UCase(cell.Value) = "YES" Then
                'Turn the variable to true if value appears in the range
                Inrng = True
                'Exit the loop to avoid time consuming
                Exit For
            End If

        Next cell

        If Inrng = True Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```